# What is the proper way to check a variable in a PHP if statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, variables

I've always checked variables in an IF statement, something like this:

`if($myvar == 1) {`

However, I've recently come across someone who always codes IF statements like this:

`if(isset($myvar) && $myvar == 1) {`

It seems like that would be redundant, like asking someone if they have a bank account and then asking if they have $20 in their bank account. My only other thought is that this may be the proper way to check variables and I was just never taught it. What does everyone think? Which is the better way?

Comment: `isset` is useful for when you're not sure if a variable has been set, such as when it's created inside of a control structure (if, else, loop). It's use is often situational.

Comment: In your question, you assume that the person already has a bank account for sure. However, what if they don't? The same applies to the code. If you're 100% sure there is that variable, it is redundant. If you can't be sure you will have to check.

Comment: Well, it turns out that the server we are on has E_NOTICE turned on, when all the servers I've worked on before have had it turned off. That makes a difference when you check a variable that isn't set.

Answer (score 0):

It is subjective to determine what better is. Let's stick to the facts:

```
if ($foo === 1) {
    //...
}
```

assumes that $foo already exists as a variable. If that's factually known, then there is no reason to check for its existence. However, if you do not know whether the variable exists, then you need to check for its existence, like

```
if (isset($foo) && ($foo === 1)) {
    //...
}
```

The second will evaluate to false if the variable does not exist and will not error out. It's uglier than the first, but safer. Such defensive methods are not necessarily in most of the cases, so when you see such a code, think about what we know about that variable. Is it guaranteed to be properly initiated in all the cases? If so, then you do not need to check for its existence. If not, then you need to check for its existence.

Answer (score 0):

This the best way to check if a variable exists in if statements
[check refer here isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

```
if (isset($variablecheck)) 
{
// some code here
}
```